# Ad Publishing services

Tags: advertising

I recently had my Google Adsense account disabled for (apparently) invalid click activity, even though I had done nothing wrong. Although I have appealed for the reinstatement of my account, I am still blocked. Is there any other Ad Publishing service I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are looking for AdSense alternatives, right?

There are around 20 alternatives. Yahoo, Kontera, Bidvertiser, etc....

I'm not affiliated but this site might be useful.

http://www.adsensealternatives.org/

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why a Google search did not find these!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for CPC, CPM or CPA ads? Text? Banner? In-line text?

Here are some CPC networks to start with:

- [Microsoft AdCenter](https://adcenter.microsoft.com/) for Yahoo / Bing ads (typically a higher CTR is seen on Yahoo)
- [Bidvertiser](http://www.bidvertiser.com/)
- [Click Booth](http://www.clickbooth.com/) (also does CPA)
- [FaceBook ads](http://www.facebook.com/FacebookAds) (higher CTR rate than Google,